# secure get through key value pair even if value doesn't exist

Tags: c#

```
            string itemnumber = "";
            itemnumber = parameter.AuxProperty["art_nr"].ToString();
            if (itemnumber == "")
            {
                string[] pnp = parameter.Name.Split('_');
                itemnumber = pnp[pnp.Length - 1];
            }
```

this is my code. I want to grab the AuxProperty with the key "art_nr" and that works as expected. But sometimes the AuxProperty["art_nr"] doesn't exist and therefore the code breaks. How can i do this in a better way so that the code won't break if there is no property["art_nr"]?

Comment: `dict.ContainsKey` ?

Comment: What type is AuxProperty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this if `AuxProperty` is in fact a *dictionary*:

```
//TODO: declare value actual type
SomeType value;

if (parameter.AuxProperty.TryGetValue("art_nr", out value)) {
  // value exists 
  itemnumber = value.ToString();
  ...
}
else {
  // No such value 
  itemnumber = "";
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add check for existence of key in key-value pair:

```
itemnumber = parameter.AuxProperty.ContainsKey("art_nr")?parameter.AuxProperty["art_nr"].ToString():String.Empty;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
itemnumber = Convert.ToString(parameter.AuxProperty["art_nr"]);
```

This would handle the NULLs

Comment: this will result into crash when art_nr is not present in the dictionary.